# Kafka - max.in.flight.requests.per.connection is per producer or session?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am going through the documentation and it is little confusing about the parameter "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection"

> The maximum number of unacknowledged requests the client will send on a single connection before blocking. Note that if this setting is set to be greater than 1 and there are failed sends, there is a risk of message re-ordering due to retries (i.e., if retries are enabled).

The phrase "unacknowledged requests" refers to per producer or per connection or per client ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Edit

Please see the answer below from Eugene. I'm not sure if this answer was wrong or if Kafka changes the behaviour in the 2 years between the answers.

## Original answer

It's per *partition*. Kafka internally might multiplex connections (e.g. to send several requests using a single connect for different topics/partitions that are handled by the same broker), or have an individual connection per partition, but these are performance concerns which are *mostly* dealt within the client.

The documentation of `retries`, sheds some more light (and clarifies that is per partition)

> Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon receiving the error. Allowing retries without setting **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection** to 1 will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches are sent to a **single partition**, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first. Note additionally that produce requests will be failed before the number of retries has been exhausted if the timeout configured by delivery.timeout.ms expires first before successful acknowledgement. Users should generally prefer to leave this config unset and instead use delivery.timeout.ms to control retry behavior.

Comment: hmm. However, it sounded like "per producer" as it is mentioned in producer config. In any case, it would have used internally "per partition" ?

Comment: It's definitely per partition. I don't know what else to say or point you to, to reassure you.

Comment: it's hard for me to agree with you. `connection` here, really means per `broker`. and the documentation uses the example about partition, only to make readers understand the implications of not setting `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to `1` when dealing with retries. you should revisit and re-read the documentation. @Nag FYI

Comment: Hi @Eugene! By no means I'm a Kafka expert and Kafka is a moving technology. Please add another answer with your findings as it might help other people having this question.

Comment: @Augusto the thing is - I am by far neither. My point of the comment is for us to both debate and may be come to a consensus (and potentially for you to update the answer).

Answer (score 3):

This is a setting *per connection, per broker*. If you have a producer, then internally it uses a `Sender Thread` that dispatches batches from the RecordAccumulator to the broker (in simpler words : sends messages). This sender thread is allowed to have a max of `${max.in.flight.requests.per.connection}` requests that it has not yet received acknowledgements from the broker. Think about this way: a sender does some operations in typical processing.

```
Drain batches -> Make Requests -> Pool Connections -> Fire Callbacks.
```

So at some point (`Pool Connections`) it can send a request to the broker, but not wait for a response, it will check for the response in the *next* cycle. It can have such *unacknowledged* requests, up to that `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` value.